# Mongoose.model('model_name') return empty object when function is required in the mongoose model schema file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I apologize if the title of the question is misleading, because I am not too sure how to explain this. I have 2 files, `matchedTransaction.js` and `player.js`.

**sharedApi/player.js**

```
const MatchedTransactionModel = require('../models/matchedTransaction');

// #1: If I try to console log here, the output will be an empty object "{}"
console.log(MatchedTransactionModel);

async function banPlayer(userId) {
  // ...
  // Because MatchedTransactionModel is an empty object, 
  // the code below will crash with the following error: 
  // "MatchedTransactionModel.findOne is not a function"
  const pendingMatchedTransaction = await MatchedTransactionModel.findOne({
    $and: [
      {
        $or: [
          { reserverAccountId: `${account._id}` },
          { sellerAccountId: `${account._id}` },
        ],
      },
      {
        $or: [
          { status: 'pendingReserverPayment' },
          { status: 'pendingSellerConfirmation' },
        ],
      },
    ],
  });
  // ...
}

module.exports = {
  banPlayer,
};
```

**models/matchedTransaction.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { banPlayer } = require('../sharedApi/player');
const MatchedTransactionSchema = new mongoose.Schema([
  {
    createdDate: {
      type: Date,
      required: true,
    },
    // ...
  },
]);

MatchedTransactionSchema.post('init', async function postInit() {
    // ...
    await banPlayer(userId);
});

const MatchedTransactionModel = mongoose.model('matchedTransactions', MatchedTransactionSchema);
module.exports = MatchedTransactionModel;
```

Notice that in **player.js** when I tried to `console.log` the required `MatchedTransactionModel`, it returns an empty object. However, if I made the following changes to **matchedTransaction.js**:

**models/matchedTransaction.js**

```
// Instead of requiring banPlayer outside, I only require it when it is used
// const { banPlayer } = require('../sharedApi/player');

MatchedTransactionSchema.post('init', async function postInit() {
    // ...
    const { banPlayer } = require('../sharedApi/player');
    await banPlayer(userId);
});
// ...
```

The output of the previously mentioned `console.log` will be a non-empty object, and `MatchedTransactionModel.findOne` is working as expected.

Why does that happen?

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see with your code is that when you define the schema on `matchedTransaction.js`, you passed an array which I think is problematic and does not make sense. You must pass an object there:

```
const MatchedTransactionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  createdDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
  // ...
});
```